# ORA:01467 Sort key too long

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find originl value for row by combining studenthistory and student table.
I have to create dynamic query which select column at runtime from student table with different schemas.
When I am executing below query with more than 90 columns it is giving the error "ORA-01467"

```
select sh.id,
       coalesce(sh.name,
                lag(sh.name ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated),
                s.name
               ) as name,
       coalesce(sh.city,
                lag(sh.city ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated),
                s.city
               ) as city,
       coalesce(sh.address,
                lag(sh.address ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated),
                s.address
               ) as address,
        s.createdDateTime,
        sh.createdDateTime as updatedDateTime,
Coalesce(sh.column1, lag(sh.column1)over(partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated desc), s.column1) as column1,
from studenthistory sh join
     student s
     on s.id = sh.id
union all
select s.id, s.name, s.city, s.address, s.createdDateTime, s.updatedDateTime
from student s;
```

Comment: Hi @Purva, you have two same query's and two different questions?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836895/dynamic-sql-in-sql-developer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Sql in SQL developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836895/dynamic-sql-in-sql-developer)

Comment: On a side note: Either your database or the query is wrong. The student history table should have a student ID and the join would have to use it: `on s.id = sh.student_id`. If  `studenthistory.id` is actually the student ID, then it should be named thus. If it is not, then you are joining on the wrong column.

Comment: This is a complicated query. It suggests the student table contains initial data only and the student history table contains all single changes since then, where the changed columns are set and the others null. Your query is supposed to show the complete student data for each day in their change history until the last entry which would represent the current data. In my opinion it would be way better, held the student table the *current* data and the history table would only be looked up when you wanted to see when a particular value was set.

Comment: Correction: For each change date you show the *previous* values. Thus the initial data is shown twice; the current data is not shown at all.

Comment: @Purva . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Explain what you are trying to do.  Provide sample data and desired results.  There may be other approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the known limitation in Oracle.

According to the Oracle docs, cause and resolution for `ORA-01467` is

> **Cause:**  A DISTINCT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or SET operation requires a
>   sort key longer than that supported by Oracle. Either too many columns
>   or too many group functions were specified in the SELECT statement.
>
> **Action:** Reduce the number of columns or group functions involved in
>   the operation.

There are 90 columns in your query which might be exceeding the **block size** of your DB.

There is no workaround for this issue except to reduce the number of columns so that data of those columns must fit into the single block.

Cheers!!